# CSS: Padding of text based on <div> width

Tags: html, css, width, padding

say I have some text displayed on an html page, which is held in a `<div>` tag. The div has `width: 100%`. I want the text to be displayed at 3/4ths of the width of the div. So, if the divider is 1000px wide, I want the left padding of the text to be 750px. How can I do this? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like: `div { padding-left: 75%; }`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_padding.asp - You need to read before posting. And @emmanuel is correct. I wonder if you even tried before posting...

Answer (score 2):

Here you have to first define the container width to 100% and then set padding to whatever % you want.

All calculations will be defined in %.

```
selector{
    width: 100%;
    padding-left: 75%; 
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
div { 
    padding-left: 75%; 
    width: 100%;
}
```